# How to convert a set of gps points to GPX file

Tags: python, geospatial, gpx

I have a csv file, it looks like:

```
id,latitude,longitude
0,51.74333,12.122905000000001
538,51.7433216,12.122895
539,51.7433266,12.1228766
540,51.743333299999996,12.1228583
541,51.7433416,12.122843300000001
542,51.743355,12.122833300000002
543,51.74337,12.1228216
```

How can I convert this file to GPX file? Can I do this with python?

Comment: the question is asked 3 years ago but if you are checking it today then you may want to have a look at this tool: https://github.com/nidhaloff/gpx_converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do this with Python, but I have used [PoiEdit](http://www.poiedit.com/downloads.htm) to convert CSV files of coordinates to GPX format. You can load the CSV in and save as a GPX file.

Answer (score 4):

See how GPX format looks like (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_Exchange_Format).

- read your CSV file, parse it
- print the beginning of the xml file (header, ...)
- go through all your gps position retrieved from the CSV file and print them in the GPX format
- print the ending of the xml file

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to use GPSBabel (https://www.gpsbabel.org) to convert the sample CSV into a set of GPX waypoints with the following command:

`gpsbabel -i unicsv -f input-file.csv -o gpx -F output-file.gpx`

Answer (score 3):

The question was asked years ago, so if you are searching for this recently and you are using python >= 3.5, you can use [gpx_converter](https://github.com/nidhaloff/gpx_converter).

Install using pip

```
pip install gpx_converter
```

then use it by calling the csv_to_gpx in your case:

```
from gpx_converter import Converter

Converter(input_file='your_input.csv').csv_to_gpx(lats_colname='latitude',
                                                 longs_colname='longitude',
                                                 output_file='your_input.gpx')
```